# Neo4j: return nodes that are directly connected as group with path length as level

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have this Cypher query:

```
MATCH path = (l:Partner)-[:HAS_MT4]->(n:Mt4)-[:HAS_REF*]->(:Mt4)<-[:HAS_MT4]-(m:Partner)
WHERE m.partner_id IN [39001174]
  AND EXISTS(n.mt4_id)
  AND n.account_type <> 'demo'
RETURN m.partner_id AS partner_id, l.partner_id AS sub_partner, LENGTH(path) AS level
```

Node labels are `Partner` and `Mt4` and the relationship types are
`HAS_MT4` and `HAS_REF`.

There are 3 partners (123456, 852963, 741852), and also a master partner 39001174.

123456 is under 39001174 and this is a direct relationship.
741852 is under 852963 who is under 39001174.
So here we have two levels that should appear together.

[graph visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uursg.png)

If I run the query above for this example I will get the following result:

```
partner id = [39001174,39001174,39001174]
sub partner = [123456,852963,741852]`
level = [1,1,2]
```

But what I want to get is something like this:

```
partner id = [39001174,39001174]
sub partner = [{123456:1},{852963:1,741852:2}]
```

I tried something like this:

```
MATCH path = (l:Partner)-[r:HAS_MT4]->(n:Mt4)-[:HAS_REF*]->(k:Mt4)<-[:HAS_MT4]-(m:Partner)
WHERE m.partner_id in [39001174]
AND exists(n.mt4_id)
AND n.account_type <>'demo'
WITH m.partner_id as partner_id, l.partner_id as sub_partner, length(path) as level
WITH partner_id, collect({sub_partner: sub_partner, level: level}) as pairs
WITH partner_id, apoc.map.groupBy(pairs, 'pair.sub_partner') as grouped_pairs
RETURN partner_id, [key IN keys(grouped_pairs) | apoc.map.fromPairs([(pair.sub_partner, pair.level)      pair IN grouped_pairs[key]])] as sub_partner
```

but I am getting syntax errors. I am not very experienced with neo4j

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATED]

You can use the APOC function [apoc.map.fromPairs](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.map/apoc.map.fromPairs/) to create maps with dynamic keys. For example:

```
MATCH path = (l:Partner)-[:HAS_MT4]->(n:Mt4)-[:HAS_REF*]->(:Mt4)<-[:HAS_MT4]-(m:Partner)
WHERE m.partner_id IN [39001174]
  AND n.mt4_id IS NOT NULL
  AND n.account_type <> 'demo'
RETURN
  m.partner_id AS partner_id,
  apoc.map.fromPairs(COLLECT([l.partner_id, LENGTH(path)])) AS sub_partner
```

Comment: Thank you but still partners are returned in separate dictionaries. What I got is [{123456:1},
{852963:1},{741852:2}]. But I need 852963 and 741852 to be in the same dictionary

Comment: Now all of them are in a single dictionary

Comment: Can you update your question to show what the exact paths look like? That is, use your first query but change it to return `path` and then show in your question what the graph visualization looks like.

Comment: I added a screenshot running my first query. numbers above partner nodes denote the level of relationship. The ones with 1 are directly referred to the master partner 39001174. There is also a network with 3 partners under the master, and all these should appear together, along with their level (length of path)